# Is a discrete harmonic function bounded below on a large portion of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ constant?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

In the paper https://doi.org/10.1215/00127094-2021-0037, the main result is if we partition the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ into unit squares (cells) so that the centers of squares have integer coordinates and identify the cells with the elements of $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Given a positive integer $N$, we denote by $Q_N$ the square on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with center at the origin and of size $(2 N+1) \times(2 N+1)$ :
$$
Q_N:=\{(n, m):|n|,|m| \leq N\} .
$$

The translation of this square by a vector $x$ with integer coordinates is denoted by $Q_N(x)$. For a set $S \subset \mathbb{Z}^2$, we denote by $|S|$ the number of elements in $S$.

Let $\varepsilon \in(0,1)$ be a positive number. We say that $|u|$ is bounded by 1 on (1- $)$ portion of the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$ if for some $N_0>0$
$$
\left|Q_N \cap\{|u| \leq 1\}\right| \geq(1-\varepsilon)\left|Q_N\right|
$$
for all $N \geq N_0$
There exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that if $u$ is a harmonic function on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $|u|$ is bounded by 1 on $(1-\varepsilon)$ portion of $\mathbb{Z}^2$, then $u$ is constant.

**My problem is whether the result is still true if we change the function $u$ to be a function that is bounded above(rather than bounded) on a large portion of $\mathbb{Z}^2$.**

Comment: On page 4 of this paper the authors write: 

"Another open question is whether Theorem 1.1 remains true if one replaces the boundedness by positivity of u on a large portion of Z^2"

Comment: So I guess this problem is still open.